# Build failed in JENKINS while trying to execute a automation script (Selenium WebDriver) Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created a Maven Project with a TestNG Test case:

Here is the code of the TestCase

```
package example;        

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;      
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;       
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;       
import org.testng.Assert;       
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;   
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;        
public class NewTest {      
    private WebDriver driver;       
    @Test              
    public void testEasy() {    
        driver.get("http://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html");  
        String title = driver.getTitle();                
        AssertJUnit.assertTrue(title.contains("Free Selenium Tutorials"));       
    }   
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {  
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
    }       
    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();          
    }       
}
```

This is the code of pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>WebdriverTest</groupId>
<artifactId>WebdriverTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXMLFiles>
                    <suiteXMLFile>WebdriverTest/testng.xml</suiteXMLFile>
                </suiteXMLFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the code of testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
   <classes>
     <class name="example.NewTest"/>
   </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I configured this pom.xml in JENKINS and created a new Maven Project and tried to execute, but the Build is getting failed. But when I execute this in Eclipse IDE as a Maven Test, the build is successful and the test script is executed.

In JENKINS the console output is saying that

### T E S T S

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) on project WebdriverTest: Error creating properties files for forking: No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provides the maven output with the `-e` option. 
Then where is located `WebdriverTest/testng.xml`? At the project root folder?

Comment: How to provide maven output with -e option?
Yes. testng.xml is located in project root folder. Project name is WebdriverTest

Comment: Try with `<suiteXMLFile>testng.xml</suiteXMLFile>` instead.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try the following instead of writing WebdriverTest/testng.xml give the absolute path or only testng.xml

2) Add permissions to the project folder.

TestNG creates a properties file and is unable to do so in jenkins case, its generally a permission issue.